# Euphemisms for stupidity

Tags: idiom

In English we can say something like "Not the sharpest pencil in the box" - Do we have a parallel kind of expression in Latin?

We can say [*brutus*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=brutus1&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) or [*stipes*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=stipes&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), which not sure if they are not more insulting, but also one-worded expressions. In searching for longer phrase only find was from Plautus:

> erus meus **elephanti corio circumtentust**, non suo, neque
> habet plus sapientiai quam lapis.

But I'm primarily looking for elegant ways to gently say someone is thickheaded.